# Как реализовать кастомные упровляющие элементы (MediaController) для VideoView?

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, видео, videoview

Для воспроизведения видеопотока из сети используется компонент VideoView.
Если упрощенно, то выглядит это примерно так:

```
final VideoView mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_view);
mVideoView.setVideoPath("http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4");
MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
mediaController.setAnchorView(mVideoView);
mVideoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
mVideoView.requestFocus();
mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
    // Close the progress bar and play the video
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mVideoView.start();
    }
});
```

Как реализовать поддержку кастомных элементов управления (кнопки play/pause, индикатор воспроизведения и т.д.). Ограничение: код должен работать под API > 15 (т.е. ExoPlayer не подходит).

Сталкивался ли кто-нибудь с такой задачей, что можете посоветовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Реализуешь свой класс расширяющий MediaController(Оригинал расширяет FrameLayout, ты тоже можешь).
`...

public class VideoControllerView extends MediaController

...`

В нем переопределяешь метод setAnchorView().Реализацию по умолчанию можешь посмотреть в самом контроллере.
`...`

```
public void setAnchorView(ViewGroup view) {
    mAnchor = view;

    FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
    );

    removeAllViews();
    View v = makeControllerView();
    addView(v, frameParams);
}
```

...

В нем ты передаешь свой макет в  makeControllerView();, который тоже надо изменить.

```
protected View makeControllerView() {
    LayoutInflater inflate = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mRoot = inflate.inflate(R.layout.media_controller, null);

    initControllerView(mRoot);

    return mRoot;
}

private void initControllerView(View v) {
    mPauseButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.pause);
    if (mPauseButton != null) {
        mPauseButton.requestFocus();
        mPauseButton.setOnClickListener(mPauseListener);
    }

    mFullscreenButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.fullscreen);
    if (mFullscreenButton != null) {
        mFullscreenButton.requestFocus();
        mFullscreenButton.setOnClickListener(mFullscreenListener);
    }

    mFfwdButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.ffwd);
    if (mFfwdButton != null) {
        mFfwdButton.setOnClickListener(mFfwdListener);
        if (!mFromXml) {
            mFfwdButton.setVisibility(mUseFastForward ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        }
    }

    mRewButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.rew);
    if (mRewButton != null) {
        mRewButton.setOnClickListener(mRewListener);
        if (!mFromXml) {
            mRewButton.setVisibility(mUseFastForward ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        }
    }

    // По дефолту вьюха будет спрятана, и показываться будет после события onTouch()
    mNextButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.next);
    if (mNextButton != null && !mFromXml && !mListenersSet) {
        mNextButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    mPrevButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.prev);
    if (mPrevButton != null && !mFromXml && !mListenersSet) {
        mPrevButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    mProgress = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.mediacontroller_progress);
    if (mProgress != null) {
        if (mProgress instanceof SeekBar) {
            SeekBar seeker = (SeekBar) mProgress;
            seeker.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(mSeekListener);
        }
        mProgress.setMax(1000);
    }

    mEndTime = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.time);
    mCurrentTime = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.time_current);
    mFormatBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    mFormatter = new Formatter(mFormatBuilder, Locale.getDefault());

    installPrevNextListeners();
}
```

Использовал эту [ссылку](http://dajver.blogspot.ru/2014/10/custom-mediacontroller-android.html)

Answer (score 0):

Думаю это вам может помочь. Если кратко - своя реализация mediaController.
Вам будет достаточно подставить свои layout метод initControllerView
http://www.brightec.co.uk/ideas/custom-android-media-controller

Comment: Желателен не такой краткий ответ. Ответ должен содержать решение, а не ссылку на решение, так как ссылка со временем может стать не рабочей.

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.